# Parse XML with PHP that contains namespaces

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to parse an XML file in PHP that looks like:

```
<post dsq:id="##Edited out##">
    <id />
    <message>##Edited out##</message>
    <createdAt>2010-07-09T16:08:44Z</createdAt>
    <author>
        <email>##Edited out##</email>
        <name>##Edited out##</name>
        <isAnonymous />
    </author>
    <ipAddress>##Edited out##</ipAddress>
    <thread dsq:id="##Edited out##" />
</post>

<post dsq:id="##Edited out##">
    <id />
    <message>##Edited out##</message>
    <createdAt>2010-07-09T16:10:07Z</createdAt>
    <author>
        <email>##Edited out##</email>
        <name>##Edited out##</name>
        <isAnonymous />
    </author>
    <ipAddress>##Edited out##</ipAddress>
    <thread dsq:id="##Edited out##" />
</post>
```

I am using simple xml to parse it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('disqus.xml');

foreach ( $xml->post as $post )
{
    echo $post['dsq:id'];
}
```

However, I am unable to get the id attribute from the post object here:

```
<post dsq:id="##Edited out##">
```

Any information on how that could be retrieved would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the namespace should be at the document root. what is it?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<disqus xmlns="http://disqus.com" xmlns:dsq="http://disqus.com/disqus-internals" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://disqus.com/api/schemas/1.0/disqus.xsd http://disqus.com/api/schemas/1.0/disqus-internals.xsd">

Comment: This looks like it'll work for you http://blog.sherifmansour.com/?p=302

Comment: Here is my updated code but it is still not working:
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('disqus.xml');

    foreach ( $xml->post as $post )
    {
     $dsq = $post->children('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
     echo $dsq->id;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('disqus.xml');

foreach ( $xml->post as $post )
{
    $dsq = $post->children('disqus.com/disqus-internals'); //should this not have http://disqus.com/disqus-internals?
    echo $dsq->id;
}
```

The one you are using, `w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`, is for the xsi namespace.